# How to change audio playrate from the browser console?

Tags: webbrowser-control, audio-streaming

I change the playrate of videos all the time. Whenever I watch youtube or BBC videos I'm able to speed them:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].playbackRate = 2.5
```

It makes learning and going through content a lot better.

I've been trying to do the same with audio and I can't.

I know there mind be podcast apps that provide up to 3x speed but I (a) only found 2x (b) not every audio is just podcast, and most importantly (c) I want to know how to do it.

For example [Making Sense Podcast](https://samharris.org/podcasts/191-early-thoughts-pandemic/)

Answer (score 0):

The same thing works with audio, but there's no guarantee that there is a tag on the page for you to reference.

The HTMLAudioElement might be instantiated with script:

```
const audio = new Audio('https://example.com/podcast.webm');
```

If that's the case, `document.getElementsByTagName()` has nothing to find.

You will need to modify the script doing the playing.

Comment: How would you do it here https://samharris.org/podcasts/191-early-thoughts-pandemic/

Comment: @relidon The same as anywhere else... inspect the script and figure it out.  Or better yet, since that's a Podcast, just load the feed in your own custom player.

Comment: I asked because I was unable to figure it out!! I want to be able to do it in the browser.